# Error using glmnet regression with metric as ROC in Caret

Tags: r, regression, r-caret, glmnet

I am training a glmnet regularized logistic regression model using Caret's trainControl and train functions as follows using metric= "ROC" and get the following error:

```
> ctrl_s10_2class <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10 , savePredictions = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE)
> model_train_glmnet_s10_2class <- train(Class ~ ZCR + Energy + SpectralC + SpectralS + SpectralE + SpectralF + SpectralR + MFCC1 + MFCC2 + MFCC3 + MFCC4 + MFCC5 + MFCC6 + MFCC7 + MFCC8 + MFCC9 + MFCC10 + MFCC11 + MFCC12 + MFCC13, data = training_s10_2class, method="glmnet", trControl = ctrl_s10_2class, metric = "ROC")

Error in evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights, ctrl = trControl, lev =  classLevels,  : 

train()'s use of ROC codes requires class probabilities. See the classProbs option of trainControl()

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.
2: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
cannnot compute class probabilities for regression
```

But I have already turned classProbs = TRUE on in trainControl function. Also, to address the warning messages, I figured I have to relevel my 2 class data which I did to find this error:

```
> sensor6data_s10_2class <- within(sensor6data_s10_2class, Class <- as.factor(Class))
> sensor6data_s10_2class$Class2 <- relevel(sensor6data_s10_2class$Class,ref="1")
> model_train_glmnet_s10_2class <- train(Class2 ~ ZCR + Energy + SpectralC + SpectralS + SpectralE + SpectralF + SpectralR + MFCC1 + MFCC2 + MFCC3 + MFCC4 + MFCC5 + MFCC6 + MFCC7 + MFCC8 + MFCC9 + MFCC10 + MFCC11 + MFCC12 + MFCC13, data = training_s10_2class, method="glmnet", trControl = ctrl_s10_2class, metric = "ROC")

Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X1, X0 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).
```

Any help to fix this with or without releveling is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: the error message says it all. your levels have the wrong naming. 0 and 1 cannot be turned into valid R names.

Comment: Convert your 0 and 1 into something like "Yes", "No".

Answer (score 0):

> 1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
>   You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.

Seems like an error with the form of data used. You could try converting it to a factor:

```
training_s10_2class$Class2 = as.factor(training_s10_2class$Class2)
```

With that, you no longer need

```
classProbs = TRUE
```

When you remove it, it should take care of your second warning

> 2: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
>   cannnot compute class probabilities for regression

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following error you get:

```
Error: Metric Accuracy not applicable for regression models
In addition: Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
```

It appears you are trying to do estimate a regression model where your outcome only has two possible values. Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.